# Bleomycin and Cannabis

Tags: cancer, lungs, recreational-drugs, chemotherapy

To my understanding, bleomycin has a considerably detrimental effect on the lungs of a patient taking it as a part of their chemotherapy regime. However, my question is, if a patient smokes cannabis (Provided it's organically grown without the interference of pesticides and alike) after the treatment, will it effect the functionally and health of the patient's lungs?

Also, what period of time after chemotherapy has ended would it be 'safe,' if at all, to use cannabis recreationally?

Just to add, I have done quite a bit of searching across the Internet for studies and patient accounts regarding the use of cannabis both amidst and post chemotherapy. Although a majority of the things I've read are accounts from patients, none mention having any difficulties with their lungs. All of the accounts I've read attest to it aiding their recovery from treatment.

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned about your lungs you could try to use [edibles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannabis_foods). They will not have any effect on your lungs.

However you should be careful because the onset of edibles takes longer (generally between 30 minutes and an hour) so it is harder to dose and generally lasts for a longer period (4-6 hours).

Another way of consuming cannabis involves the use of a [vaporizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaporizer_(inhalation_device)). Although this might still have some effect on your lungs. It uses [convection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection) instead of [combustion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combustion) of the cannabis leaving any plant material that has a lower vaporization point than the used temperature on the vaporizer behind. The benefit of this method is that the onset is as fast as smoking because the uptake of the active compounds is similar to smoking it so it is easier to dose.

I am not sure how long you have to wait after your treatment so you should consult your doctor about it but I have heard of people using it during chemotherapy already to help combat the nausea.

Comment: Can you please add sources for a few of your statements (vaporizer effects, at least).  Also, while you say that a doctor should be consulted (which they should!), I feel like you didn't take into account that the OP was asking specifically about *bleomycin*, which damages the lungs. The other people you heard about might have taken different medication. Even a vaporizer might be a very, very bad idea in this case.

Comment: @YviDe I could not find a clear source for effects but since it follows a similar path as smoking (through the lungs) i have tried to make that as clear as possible. I leave the part open about bleomycin because that is outside of my knowledge. If OP wants to be 100% sure i think he is better of taking small amounts of edibles to see where his comfort zone is.